# Как сделать выколотую круговую диаграмму в Holo graph library?

Tags: java, android, android-library

А то по дефолту она, скажем так, закрашена полностью.

Comment: Приведите пример кода, пожалуйста

Comment: Я привёл метод в ответе и добавил ваш код в вопрос

Comment: Если ответ подошёл - отметьте его как верный, если возникнут вопросы - пишите в комментарии

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы задать внутренний радиус у PieGraph, необходимо вызвать метод:

```
pg.setInnerCircleRatio(int holeSize);
```

Для того чтобы настроить отступ между "кусками пирога" нужно вызвать:

```
pg.setPadding(int padding);
```

Comment: Благодарю вас )

Comment: @SadRat, не за что :-)  С Новым Годом Вас! :-)